# Bayesian Inference to determining best schedule to update movies

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models

We've got around 2 million movies in our database. The data for all those movies is extracted from a third party service. Every week we get new movies in our database (when they're created at 3rd party service). All movies have to be updated after creation. The thing to solve here is the best schedule to check for updates.

For example, let's say that movie A is created on october 1st. My first approach is to check for updates more frequently at the beginning and less frequently as time from creation passes. So, updating check schedule would be something like:

1st check: 1 week after creation (1 week AC)
2nd check: 1 month AC
3rd check: 2 months AC
4th check: 6 months AC
Recurrent following checks: 1 every year.

This schedule tries to reflect the likelihood of a movie being updated since it was created in 3rd party source database.

It's not accurate at all, and I guess the schedule should be affected by new data. For instance, if there is no update after first 3 months, the likelihood of the movie being updated in the next couple of months might be greater than other movies which have been updated.

Not sure how to apply Bayesian Inference in this case or if it is the best approach. I have the intuition that following 80/20 rule might be enough for this case.

Comment: I would suggest some exploratory analysis first: e.g., see if the intervals between updates strongly depend on the number of previous updates, or on the time since creation, or maybe just on something completely different, like some category of the movie.
Also, check if updates of different movies cluster in time.

Comment: Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis may give you some leads to follow.